# Recognition of British Computer Society Higher Education for migration for the following countries

Tags: australia, immigration, education, new-zealand, qualifications

I'm an IT support engineer with 3 Years experience, currently holding a [Professional Graduate Diploma in IT (PGD)(BCS)](http://www.bcs.org/category/18013) which is equivalent to a university honors degree in England, and is recognized as a level 6 qualification. But I am wondering whether my qualifications will be recognized in New Zealand and Australia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to NZQF (New Zealand Qualifications Framework) 
Postgraduate diplomas and certificates, Bachelors degrees with Honours is LEVEL 8 and can score 50 points
Bachelors degrees, Graduate diplomas is LEVEL 7 and can score 50 points
Since you mentioned your qualification is equivalent to a university honors degree in England, it should be recognized by NZQF as LEVEL 8
Please refer the below link,
http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/NZRegisterOfQualityAssuredQualifications.htm